# How to store changed visibility of view in Android Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity, where in i have a button (Visible) and an EditText(invisible).

When I click on button, edit text becomes visible. Now if I close my app, I want this state to be saved. I want to save the visible state of Edit Text.

I looked up the web, and it states that if I have onSaveInstanceState overridden in the activity then it should be alright.

Inside the onSaveInstanceState, I am just doing a call to super function.

In my onCreate method, I have super.onCreate.

Is there anything else that needs to be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can retrieve the value from onSaveInstanceState when the configuration changes (e.g. rotation) but when you close your app (e.g back button) then you need to retrieve the state from the persistence storage like shared preferences.

```
// obtain shared preferences
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs_file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);

// Update shared preferences file
@Override
public void onPause() {
    sharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
    prefsEditor.putInt("visibility", mEditText.getVisibility());
    super.onPause();
}
```

Then read it on onResume()

```
 int visibility =  preferences.getInt("visibility", 0);
 mEditText.setVisibility(visibility);
```

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: FYI, this answer assumes this is to save state across configuration changes -- not persistent state saving.

Keep a boolean value somewhere, and save/restore that when necessary. For example:

```
private static final String EDIT_TEXT_VISIBLE = "edit_text_visible";
private boolean mEditTextVisible;

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean(EDIT_TEXT_VISIBLE, mEditTextVisible);
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedState) {
    super.onCreate(savedState);

    // Do your view initialization...

    // If there's saved state, restore the state that you saved,
    // and apply it to the EditText.
    if (savedState != null) {
        mEditTextVisible = savedState.getBoolean(EDIT_TEXT_VISIBLE);
        mEditText.setVisibility(mEditTextVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: In OnCreate, my bundle is always null. Why is that? Even if I am not putting anything in outState, super.onSaveInstanceState call should save something in bundle right?

Comment: It's null because you close your app. Please check my answer

Comment: Wait, if you close your app? Then no, you should save this to persistent storage somewhere (SharedPreferences, etc.) `onSaveInstanceState()` just retains data across configuration changes or it being killed off in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you forget the part where you put the data in the Bundle in onSaveInstanceState and retrieve it in onCreate?

You dont just call the super method in onSaveInstance state, you put your data in the Bundle also.

The other quick option is to store these values in a SharedPreference